# SQL Table design question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please ignore this question if it sounds stupid to you.

I have SQL table (SQL Server) for photo albums and it has 20+ columns & it will hold millions of albums.

I need to designate some albums as Promoted and some as Featured every week.
I also need a very efficient way to get these albums (page by page) when I show it to users.

How should I design this?

**option 1:**
 I can create another table just to store the ids of the promoted and featured albums like this and then join the main albums table to get the set of columns I need.

**table designated_albums:**

```
album_id  promoted_featured
    1         1
    5         0
    7         1
    15        0
```

The query for promoted will return 1, 7
The query for featured will return 5, 15

**Option 2:**
 I can add 1 column store 1 if promoted and 0 if featured. Otherwise it is null
 I can then query to check for 1 in that column for promoted albums & 0 for featured.

**Option 3:**
 I can add 2 bit columns: one for promoted (0/1) and one for featured(0/1)

Which way would perform better?

**EDIT:
The design should be efficient in SQL 2008 as well. Right now I have SQL 2005.**

Comment: Can "promoted" be independent of "featured"?

Comment: Yes. An album can be either Promoted or Featured at any given time. Not both.

Comment: if you're not going to have an album be promoted & featured at once, one column is fine. even if you are, just use bit comparison (0x01 for featured, 0x02 for promoted, and probably name it something other than just promoted_featured if you wanted to use the other bits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the albums which are promoted and/or featured are a small subset of 'all' albums, then you should put them in a separate table.

If the promoted and/or featured albums are a significant proportion of the overall set then performance will be better if you add columns to your existing table.

I'm going to assume the first case; you have 'millions' of albums, and I'm sure you aren't promoting or featuring more than a few thousand, and definitely not tens of thousands.  The lookup in this much smaller table will be very fast, and the join will also be fast provided that the 'main' table is clustered on primary key.

Comment: They are only a small subset of the total rows.

Answer (score 3):

You mention a pending migration to SQL 2008.  Filtered indexes were added in that release.  A lot of the "use a different table" has to do with quick data access.  By using a filtered index, you can get the best of both worlds (i.e. store the various statuses with your data while still being able to query a small table).  It might be worth exploring when you're able to use SQL 2008 as a platform

Comment: +1.2008 / R2 and you store it in the table as a bit if you want. Filtred index on teh bit, finished.

Comment: Although it's not mentioned in the answers above, a lot of the "use a different table" has to do with experience. Over time, the OP is probably going to want to add different attributes (columns) to promoted albums than to featured albums. Since they're logically different things in the first place, different tables makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thank you Ben Thul, Tom Tom and Catcall. I appreciate all of you.

Comment: @Catcall: I disagree that they're intrinsically different things.  To me, it seems that having an album be promoted or featured is a display issue only.  Of course, I could be wrong, but I'm a fan of solving today's problems today and tomorrow's problems tomorrow.

Comment: @Ben Thul: It's an identification *and* display issue.

Comment: And the database doesn't care a whit about how its data is displayed. Separate tables for logically distinct things solves today's problems today and at least part of tomorrow's problems today. That's leverage.

Answer (score 2):

Create another table. A small table is fast to query. Join by PK with your main table will be also fast. Also, a small table is easy to modify when (not whether, you know) requirements change.

Think about how many values in an extra column of a main table would be unused and just store the same 'inactive' value. And the bigger the table rows, the slower is access to the entire table.

Comment: How can I split the points for the answer between Kirk and 9000? Both of these are similar and I am going to accept both. Cam I do it?

Comment: No need to split points; Kirk's answer has more relevant detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a master table called Status, which will have following columns.

Status_tb

```
status_id status_name
0         None
1         Feautured
2         Promoted
3         Both
```

Note: Both means both promoted and featured.

Now in the album transactional table, I will add a column called status_id.  This will have a fk reference to the master table.

This is clean and also efficient. ( Highly skewed columns and hence helps in histograms and partitions also)

Comment: I'm not convinced this is any better than a '1' for featured, '0' for promoted, and 'null' for everything else - without a join.  This does allow for expansion, but I'd worry about expansion only when it is a reasonable possibility.

Comment: Hmmm. What if you want a filter albums based on state. In that case having a master table helps me to get the list of available states for the user to query. Also the boolean solution you mentioned, has the the logic implicit. ( as a designer you had decided 0 as preferred and 1 as feautured), don't you think you are compromising readability of your program ( and consequently the design). My solution will make the logic more explicit and cleaner to understand, don't you think.

Comment: I need faster solution. By faster I mean: SEEK on the table when I am reading by select command. This is because I will have a large number of albums.

Comment: Will partition be a problem, if I create a separate table as suggested by Kirk?

Comment: You do not have to create a seperate table if you perform partition. Lets say I create partition based on the video state. ( none, featured and promoted ), then based on the query the query will directly run on the partition ( and will not perform a full table scan).

Comment: I know you are using sql-server. I am an Oracle guy and hence forgive me if some of my terminologies are oracle specific. Even if its a huge table, If I create the correct index, then the query will only perform index scan. If there are IO concerns ( explain plan will tell me if there is one), then I will create a partition. Creating a seperate table is similiar to creating a partition. ( Oracle CBO will create histograms or buckets for skewed columns to optimize, I am sure sql server does that also)